Are there badges that do not show up on badges under the profile?
I recently got a badge "Tumbleweed" which is not listed on "choose next badge to track". How can one know which badges exist in total? 

You can see the complete list in this link: Complete Badge List
You can even see how many have been awarded. 
BR
